# How can I change WPF ComboBox dropdown width in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm currently working on C# WPF project, one thing I can't seem to do is  - How do I change the ComboBox dropdown width, because every time I had Items the dropdown width takes the size of the longest item(or string);

How can I fix this Please Help fellow developers/programmers !!!!

Comment: What exactly do you want the drop down width to be?

Comment: You can simply set an absolute width on the template you use to show the items.

Comment: There are several ways to do that. Simply, bind `ComboBoxItem.Width` to the `ComboBox.ActualWidth`

Comment: Hamlet Hakobyan ; How do I go about that ?

Answer (score 11):

Set the ItemContainerStyle of the ComboBoxItem like this:

```
 <ComboBox Width="50" Height="40">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="this is Item One "/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="this is Item "/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="this is "/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="this "/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Also there is the MaxHeight attribute that might be usefull

Comment: This affects the container,  not the dropdown itself. For instance, I set it to 200 but my ComboBox itself was 1000, so this content appeared centered in the dropdown.  What I'm trying to do is limit the width of the dropdown to match the combo box itself.